# Запятая перед союзом «или» в вопросительном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, или

> Не прячьте ваши денежки, или Выведут ли из тени экономику?

Так как предложение вопросительное, стоит ли ставить запятую перед «или»?

Answer (score 2):

Насчёт запятой никакого сомнения нет: запятая необходима, так как это двойное название одного и того же. Первая часть предложения НЕ вопросительная, а побудительная. Вторая - вопрос.